# I want to use 3 args The command should be like this: /event pop on

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

as I said in the title I want to make the following 2 commands:           /event pvp on

and /event pop off
it is not working. Help me pls.
btw I'm new in Coding Java

this is my code:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args, String arg2) {

    Player player = (Player) sender;
    if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("event")) {
        if(args.length == 0) {
            player.sendMessage("Syntax: /event (Event) on/off");
            return true;
        } else if(args.length == 1) {
            String mode = args[0];
            if(mode.equalsIgnoreCase("pvp")) {
                if(arg2.length() == 1) {
                    String Modus = arg2;
                    if(Modus.equalsIgnoreCase("on")) {


               new PlayerRDEvent(this);


                for(Player onps : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()){
                    onps.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD +  "PvP" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Event" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "]" + ChatColor.GRAY + "Das PvP Event hat begonnen!");
                     onps.playSound(onps.getLocation(), Sound.ARROW_HIT, 2, 0);
                }}}
                return true;
            } else if(mode.equalsIgnoreCase("off")) {
                 for(Player onps2 : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()){
                    onps2.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD +  "PvP" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Event" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "]" + ChatColor.GRAY + "Das PvP Event ist zu ende!");
                     onps2.playSound(onps2.getLocation(), Sound.ARROW_HIT, 2, 0);}
                HandlerList.unregisterAll();




                return true;
            } else {
                player.sendMessage("Use: /event (event) on/off");

            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using mode as a variable for `args[0]` and didn't use it to check if it was on. To check for the off/on string, equate `mode` to `args[1]` (Second element in array, because the first one would be pvp) and check before the conditions if `args[0]` is equal to pvp

Also, you cannot add the parameter `String arg2` if you are overriding the method from JavaPlugin - so just use the default parameters of the method **onCommand**, 
see: [OnCommand Bukkit method](http://bukkit.wikia.com/wiki/OnCommand)

**Code:**

```
 Player player = (Player) sender;
    if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("event")) {
        if (args[0].equals("pvp")) { //check if args[0] is pvp, you can add an else statement to send an error message if it is not pvp, or manipulate it differently
            if (args.length != 2) { //if it does not contain both [pvp] and [off/on]
                player.sendMessage("Syntax: /event (Event) on/off");
                return true;
            } else { //if args length = 2
                String mode = args[1]; //[off/on]
                if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("on")) { //if args[1] is "on"


                    for (Player onps : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                        onps.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "PvP" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Event" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "]" + ChatColor.GRAY + "Das PvP Event hat begonnen!");
                        onps.playSound(onps.getLocation(), Sound.ARROW_HIT, 2, 0);
                    }
                    return true;


                } else if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("off")) { //if args[1] is "off"
                    for (Player onps2 : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                        onps2.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "PvP" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Event" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "]" + ChatColor.GRAY + "Das PvP Event ist zu ende!");
                        onps2.playSound(onps2.getLocation(), Sound.ARROW_HIT, 2, 0);
                    }
                    HandlerList.unregisterAll();
                    return true;


                } else {
                    player.sendMessage("Use: /event (event) on/off");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

I really suggest you implement some sort of command listener in the near future instead of checking for each command on the onCommand method as it makes your code cleaner and easier to read

Comment: can you recommend any tutorial for the command listener you mentioned in your answer

Comment: @Leopa oh, its a feature you have to implement by yourself. Basically you have to make another class that handles different commands, you can pass on args[0] as a constructor parameter for that class. A useful link: https://bukkit.org/threads/tutorial-using-multiple-classes.179833/

Comment: still not woking

Comment: What is not working, exactly? Are you getting any error message or is it compiling fine but doesn't work? Can you please paste your code and attach a link to the paste url. Thanks